# Making change in Base Activity to reflect changes in All derived Activities?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, abstract-class

I have a

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

protected void setCustomHeader(String title,String subText){
   }
}
```

and `two` other Classes Extending the `BaseActivity` class.

```
public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity {
           setCustomHeader("List","Child1");
}
```

&

```
public class DetailsActivity extends BaseActivity {
         setCustomHeader("Details","Child2");
}
```

The `BaseActivity` generally reduces the code here of creating Custom Action Bar in all child activities, which works just fine.

I wish to change the `Custom Header` in the `BaseActivity` on some Event (say `BroadcastReciever`) such that all the other `ChildActivity`(here ListActivity n DetailsActivity) Extending the BaseActivity also get updated.

Is it possible to change `BaseActivity` only and without making changes to ChildActivity I enforce all childrenActivities to update its `Custom Header` based on the event recieved from `Broadcast reciever`?

`EDIT:` I don't want to write a receiver for each and every activity so I am trying this approach, please suggest if any better approaches are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I modified the Method of the `baseActivity` on the Broadcast event and tested I realized that all the children automatically were updated, and hence got what i was looking for.

That was is purpose of Inheritance of classes.

Actually I was confronted by someone that the children won't get updated from the Base and hence posted without testing.

PS: whenever you are confronted by anyone, just never give up, you need to test the working of your implementation.

`Lesson learnt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this in several ways, but all of which will require a check in the BaseActivity's `onResume()` to reset the theme appropriately when they're actually being displayed...

First (and I'm probably going to get chewed out for suggesting this) and quickest would be to use a `static variable` containing the appropriate values of whatever you're trying to accomplish.

```
private static WhateverData o;
```

All you'd have to do is call:

```
public static void set(WhateverData o){
    BaseActivity.o = o;
}
```

And in your `Activity's onResume()` method you would recreate whatever `Views` you want, based on the currently set static object.

Why is this approach not the best? There are a couple reasons. Using non-final static variables runs a bigger risk of NPE's (you definitely need to handle a default case where the value is null) and the data may not always be available when needed (due to the OS killing it, etc.).

Now, a better approach could be to use the `SharedPreferences` in the same way you'd use the static variable. This will ensure that the data persists and is always available (but, again, you should still handle the default null case).

```
public static WhateverData getWhateverData(Context context){
    return context.getSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.class.getName(), 0).getWhateverData("data_key", default);
}

public static void setWhateverData(Context context, WhateverData o){
    context.getSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.class.getName(), 0).edit().putWhateverData("data_key", o).commit();
}
```

And then for actually using it, you can just override `onResume()` once in your `BaseActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WhateverData data = BaseActivity.getWhateverData(this);
    // Now do something cool with that data
}
```

Clearly you have to implement those methods to handle whatever type of data WhateverData is, but I'm just trying to point you in the right direction...

Comment: `OnResume` will be called whenever the `Activity` comes foreground, the event from `BroadCast` can be available while the `Activity` is in Foreground, so this doesn't help is such situation

Comment: So in the Receiver you set the static method and check for an active Activity. If there is one and it's an instance of your BaseActivity, call the method to rebuild it. All other Activity's will naturally inherit that state once they are resumed.

Comment: Just realized, that the children activities automatically gets an update if the base Activities method is changed, no special steps are required to modify children. Tested the same, cheers for the help

Answer (score 0):

In this BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity {
  protected abstract void refresh();
}
```

And your child Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {
   protected void refresh(){
    // This your code
    }
}
```